# Gulp error using react, .NET Core, es2015, babel, browserify

Tags: gulp, ecmascript-6, asp.net-core

I am trying to bundle my project, but I am getting this error with any build task. I have tried three separate bundle methods using Visual Studio in a .NET Core app. Here is one:

```
gulp.task('babelify', function () {
    return browserify({
        extensions: ['.jsx', '.js'],
        entries: 'Client/app/main.js',
    })
      .transform(babelify.configure({ presets: ["es2015","react"] }))
      .bundle()
      .on("error", function (err) { console.log("Error : " + err.message); })
      .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('.wwwroot/js'));
});
```

Here is my error:

```
Unexpected token ILLEGAL while parsing file: C:\code\PasswordManager\src\PasswordManager.Web\Client\app\main.js
Process terminated with code 0.
```

This bundle build works on OSX with Node, but when porting to .NET Core, it breaks.

Any suggestions? I have heard Windows has some node_module nesting issues...

Here is `main.js`, but I really do not think this is the issue:

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'react-router';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
import routes from './routes';
import Header from './components/Header';

let history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={history}>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lesson learned. When porting from OSX to Windows, drop your package.json file and start from scratch. Some packages are operating system dependent...

Comment: Says I have to wait another day to do so ;)